# PostgreSQL/ Java Looping Until User Enters a UserName that doesn't exist

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, while-loop

I am trying to create a loop that continues to loop until the user enters a username that does not exist. For example, maryj exists in the database. Tracing the code, I first enter maryj which I will enter the while loop and ask the user to `Please enter a another username.Enter your username:`. I enter maryj again but the loop does not ask me to enter another username as it should. It moves own to the next bit of code. It seems like the while loop only works after the first trial but not if I enter the same username multiple times. The code is below.

```
  public void register() throws SQLException
  {

  Scanner stdin;
  String sql_statement;
  Statement select = connection.createStatement();

  stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter your user name: ");
  user_name = stdin.next();


  sqlz_statement = "SELECT " + "user_name " + "FROM" + " users" + " where user_name = "
        + "'" + user_name + "'";

  result = select.executeQuery(sql_statement);

  while(result.next())
  {
     System.out.println("Please select another username.");
     System.out.print("Enter your user name: ");
     user_name = stdin.next();
  }

  System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
  System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");

  } // method register
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **not** concatenate user input into a SQL query. [Learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: There is no loop for asking the question, only a loop that processes the complete result of the query

Comment: You can either call the function recursively, by replacing user_name=stdin.next()  with register(). Also, you should use result.hasNext() instead of result.next() in the while loop.

Comment: @Jaiprakash Thank you! I do have a question does that affect that I after the username is entered I have to add it to the database

Comment: @AbbyS As far as I understood the comment, the above code will not add to the username to the database. If you want you will have to do it in the code.

Comment: @Jaiprakash After the process is complete with making sure the username does not exist in the database. I then will have to add the username to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your while it's wrong, because you only look in the DB once, you should chnage it this way:

```
  Boolean exist=true;
  while (exist) {
      System.out.print("Enter your user name: ");
      user_name = stdin.next();
      sqlz_statement = "SELECT " + "user_name " + "FROM" + " users" + " where user_name = "
            + "'" + user_name + "'";
      result = select.executeQuery(sql_statement);
      if (!result.next()) {exist=false}
      else {System.out.println("Please select another username.");}
  }  
  System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
  System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
```